# Workaround for formatting code in HTML with pre tags?

Tags: python, html

I'm working with a Python script that's used to write HTML pages. It uses a series of switches to determine what page is written. It also uses `<pre>` tags for code samples. The thing I don't like about `<pre>` tags is that it messes up the formatting within the .py script. The hierarchy of if/elif/else conditionals is broken because the tags are now left justified. I know `<pre>` tags take into account whitespace, but is there anyway to format the field within the Python script so that the code is more legible and better formatted?

So right now it's as such

```
def main():
    if true:
        page=<b>This is a sample</b>
<pre>
This is now left justified to match the pre tag but looks ugly in the code
</pre>
    else:
       page="<b>This would look much better</b>
       <pre>
            But all the white spacing to keep it aligned makes the HTML page 
            formatted wrong but it is much easier to read, edit here in the script
       </pre>
    return page
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your strings out to globals, perhaps in a separate module even:

```
sample_page = '''\
<b>This is a sample</b>
<pre>
This is now left justified to match the pre tag but looks ugly in the code
</pre>
'''

better_sample = '''\
<b>This would look much better</b>
<pre>
    But all the white spacing to keep it aligned makes the HTML page 
    formatted wrong but it is much easier to read, edit here in the script
</pre>
'''
```

Note how these are *entirely* unindented.

Then use these in your regular flow:

```
if True:
    page = sample_page
else:
    page = better_sample
```

You can easily combine that with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); placeholders in the string variables, using `str.format()` to fill these out in your normal flow.

A betters solution still would be to use a template engine to produce your HTML output, like [Chameleon](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not efficient, but I would concatenate the strings like so:

```
def main():
    if True:
        page = "<b>This is a sample</b>\n"
        page += "<pre>\nThis is now left justified...\n</pre>"
    else:
        page = "<b>...</b>"
        page += "..."
```

The "\n" characters will be interpreted as newlines.  In this case, The *This* in the first example will be left justified.  Simply add spaces as needed.

If you want to make the process a bit more efficient, you could use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), like this:

```
import StringIO


def main():
    text = None
    if True:
        page = StringIO.StringIO()
        page.write("<b>Testing</b>\n")
        page.write("<pre>\nThis is left justified.\n</pre>")
    else:
        pass

    text = page.getvalue()
    page.close()
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print main()
```

**Note #1**: The newline characters outside of the  tags are not needed, since HTML doesn't care about whitespace.  It's mainly for readability if you happen to be reading the source.

**Note #2**: I wouldn't use this in any kind of production environment, but it works for simple things.